# How can I make condition with UNIQUE filter?

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I use angular-filter by a8m... https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter

How can I make condition with UNIQUE filter
if UNIQUE remove same object
$scope.param=1
else(if UNIQUE not remove objects)
$scope.param=2